# put text above unicode character and change width of the unicode character

Tags: css

I want to put a string above to the unicode character.

something like:

[image]

so I have to do two things:

```
1) change the width of the unicode character
2) put the string above the unicode character
```

this is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/EXCU8/32/

and this is my css:

```
font.sub-menu-item:before {
    content: "\21C0";
    width:200px;
}

div.upperChar {
    padding-top:30px;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the font's size. You can control its position with the `margin`.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/EXCU8/33/)

```
font.sub-menu-item:before {
    content: "\21C0";
    font-size: 170px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -15px;
}
```

Also, why do you need an extra element for this? Here's a better example using the `:after` pseudo class and only one element.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/EXCU8/35/)

```
div.upperChar:after {
    content: "\21C0";
    font-size: 170px;
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```